# how to delete the first key by adding orders in redis

Tags: hash, redis

there are some values in a hash queue of redis, and the program needs to keep that queue only have 3 members.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET hash2 user1 "name1"

127.0.0.1:6379> HSET hash2 user2 "name2"

127.0.0.1:6379> HSET hash2 user3 "name3"
```

when inserting a new key "user4", the queue in the program should remove the "user1" from hash2.

We know that the list has a "ltrim" function could do keep a list in a fixed count easily.

As for hash, I could not find a function to do that easily. 
If the count of hash2 is less than 512, the redis stored the keys by "ziplist" data structure. It's behavior just like a sequence list.
Is there a way to keep a hash queue in a fixed number, when a new value inserting to that queue, the key which is the earliest into the queue should be removed?

By now, I can do it by below way when inserting a new value into a hash queue:

1. read the length of the hash2
2. if the length is less than 3, inserting into the queue directly, else do the step 3.
3. if the length is greater than 3, **read all of keys ** from the redis
4. delete the first one
5. inserting the new vlaue into the hash queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements in `HASH` have no order, and you cannot tell which one is the oldest/latest. So there's no command similar to `ltrim` for `HASH`.

The reason that your solution can work is that Redis encodes small hash into *zipmap*. Just as you mentioned, *zipmap* is similar to `LIST`, and elements are ordered by the time that it inserted into. However, It's NOT a good idea to rely on that. If someone changes the configuration of `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and `hash-max-zipmap-value`, or the number of your `HASH` exceeds the limit, your solution might fail.

**Solution**

> Use an extra LIST to record the order

Instead of counting on *zipmap*'s order, you can record the order of element/field with an extra `LIST`. Each time you insert an element in `HASH`, also `rpush` the field into the `LIST`. If the size of the `HASH` reaches the limit, `lpop` the first element in the `LIST`, and remove the corresponding field in `HASH`.

```
HSET hash2 user1 "name1"
RPUSH list2 user1
HSET hash2 user2 "name2"
RPUSH list2 user2
HSET hash2 user3 "name3"
RPUSH list2 user3
HSET hash2 user4 "name4"  // reach the limit
LPOP list2   // remove the oldest from list to get "user1"
HDEL hash2 user1  // remove it from hash
```

Comment: sorry to update the status late. I agree with you that it's not a good a idea to rely on the zipmap.

Comment: In my business, I just read the data which was wrote by others. So it's not convenient to make an extra LIST. I will try to if the HASH can be change to the LIST. Many Thanks.